# How to create an empty mxn table in latex using \foreach?

Tags: longtable, foreach, pgffor

I want to create an mxn table using `pgffor`. The following code is my try and gives the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgffor@endgroup ...d {\pgffor@remember@once@code 
                                                  }\fi \ifx \pgffor@remember...
l.18 ^^I}
         
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

and also

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.18 ^^I}
         
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
```

I wanted to do this in an longtable environment and so, the solution given by `pgfplot` or `tikzmatrix` wont work for me.

**My MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{*{5}{|l|}}
        \foreach \i in {1,..,5}{
            \foreach \j in {1,..,4}{ & } \\
        }
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can't use `\foreach` inside the table as it puts each item in a group and `{&}` doesn't work. You can do the loop before the table, building up a macro with the table body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot work for an important reason, namely that
`\foreach` doesn't work as you may think: it doesn't just spit out the given code and, even if it did, you cannot start a loop in a table cell ending it in another.

You need *expandable* loops or to build the table body step by step and then deliver it.

I'll present two solutions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{pgffor} % only for the second solution

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\emptytable}{mm}
 {% #1 = number of rows
  % #2 = number of columns
  \int_set:Nn \l__david_empty_cols_int { #2 }
  \begin{tabular}{|*{#2}{c|}}
  \hline
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 }
   {
    \int_step_function:nN { #2 } \__david_empty_row:n
   }
  \end{tabular}
 }

\int_new:N \l__david_empty_cols_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__david_empty_row:n
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 = \l__david_empty_cols_int } { \\ \hline } { & }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\emptytablebody}{}% initialize

\newcommand{\emptytableforeach}[2]{%
  \gdef\emptytablebody{}%
  \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{%
    \foreach \j in { 2,...,#2 }{%
      \xdef\emptytablebody{%
        \unexpanded\expandafter{\emptytablebody &}
      }%
    }%
    \xdef\emptytablebody{%
      \unexpanded\expandafter{\emptytablebody}
      \noexpand\\\noexpand\hline
    }%
  }%
  \begin{tabular}{|*{#2}{c|}}
  \hline\emptytablebody
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\emptytable{5}{6}

\bigskip

\emptytableforeach{5}{6}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first solution does all the basic work in the first cell, but as `\prg_replicate:nn` and `\int_step_function:nN` deliver their result all at once and only after that the first item is examined, everything works because the cells end when all the “expanded code” is present in the input stream.

In the second solution, we need a container to be globally populated step by step. After that we can deliver it.

Comment: That shows the greater knowledge in latex. Thanks a lot Sir.